# Why not to ask public about new features idea? e.g. unicorn and unicoins

Tags: discussion, answers, etiquette, unicorns

Should there be a vote for this?

Also some announcement with detailed description would be great to receive.

Comment: Personally I really don't like the idea of unicorns. Why couldn't they do something different? +1

Comment: Unicorns don't need announcements or descriptions.

Comment: There is much better things you can do, like building video section, providing some teaching materials.

I bet the whole idea of unicorns-unicoins was made by some 'crazy' marketing specialist with no idea of the whole stackoverflow community and what is good for it.

Comment: Unicorns bring joy and love to the world they need no vote.

Comment: It wouldn't be a surprise if we were asked to vote on the April Fool's idea first.

Comment: @AndrewMartin Guy got a point, though: there are more pressing development needs on SE than an April's Fool this elaborate. But then, even devs are allowed some downtime and fun, I hear.

Comment: @Raphael: Users have made it this elaborate. It's a fun little icon with not a lot else going on and the community has blown it up to epic (and rather awesome) levels. I don't doubt that the mods are hard at work on other pressing needs. But I do like that a community _this_ serious can have one day where everything just descends into chaos :)

Comment: @AndrewMartin well done boy, you've done your research. There you go have some points to your personal self esteem. I bet this is the only thing you can be proud of .... Duh

Comment: @d689p: Nah, I'm a happy-go-lucky fella. Plenty to be proud of :)

Comment: @AndrewMartin the sad thing is that only you think this way in your head. The real danger poses people, who really think they are something, whereas the reality dictates the opposite. You take care and be proud of yourself.

Comment: @d689p: To be honest, this is a fun day and this is only the meta site. But be careful. You're rather rude in your comments and that's a surefire way not to fit in to this community. Just a piece of friendly advice (since telling someone they've nothing to be proud of in life is just belittling and unfriendly). If you carry it on, you _will_ run the risk of people not being as willing to help you.

Comment: @AndrewMartin my piece of advice is that you should not be so quick with your prejudgement opinion, quotes. And it wasn't directed to you, or anybody here. It might not even be the truth, I am assuming it might exist, as history shows. Think twice before act and be humble in your saying. The whole point of this thread was an open discussion, not the opportunity to point with the fingers. Some people seems to be don't get this. The End

Comment: @d689p: Sure. But before commenting on all the things SO needs to do better and criticising the so called market specialist you referenced, you should realise you _are_ new to the site and take some time to understand how it works. For example - better teaching materials. SO doesn't cater for this. Whilst the meta is a discussion based area, none of the main sites are. They are _strictly_ Q&A. finally, you're asking for discussion on a fun (and short time only) issue, which is why no one is getting into it. Anyways, have to head on and our comments are turning into chat (not encouraged).

Answer (score 6):

Yes there should be a vote whether you have to read the date and enter [april-fools](/questions/tagged/april-fools) or [unicoins](/questions/tagged/unicoins) as tag in your question.

I will vote it up!