# Is there a unicorn-unicoins boss? Creator?

Tags: discussion, unicoins, unicorns

Whose idea was to implement unicorn-unicoins?

Please clarify what is the idea behind it?

Answer (score 13):

The idea came from one of our 'crazy' marketing specialists with no idea of the whole Stack Overflow community and what is good for it.

<sub>Source: [you](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/227612/why-not-to-ask-public-about-new-features-idea-e-g-unicorn-and-unicoins#comment745834_227612)</sub>

Comment: Ohh you, the source of all goodness. Thx for that, you made my day, got really hooked up on this thing. You take care and hope to see more of a fun projects. Hope you'll do something really brilliant in the future, as there is some potential :-)

Answer (score 5):

Unicorns do not need a reason. Unicorns *are* the reason. They are also self-perpetuating and need no creator.

Answer (score 1):

Clearly it was an **Intelligent Designer** who put them here to guide us the way to **Nirvana**!

To reach Nirvana simply stand in front of Unicorn, ask it politely to lower its head, then accelerate. Instant Relieve of all burdens guarenteed!

Comment: Warning: depending on your girth and the horn's size, you may still be there for another round.

Comment: @FrédéricHamidi If your acceleration is found lacking by the Creator you are not yet ready for enlightenment.